# How do I back up On Premise Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to Azure cloud

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure-sql-database, cloud

I have a 50 GB hosted SQL Server database at SoftLayer.

I want to do backups to cloud storage, as the SoftLayer managed SQL Server backups are ridiculously priced. Eventually we will totally move away from their hosting model to pure cloud, but that is a topic for another question.

For the time being, I want to automate backup of "on premise" SQL Server databases to a cloud storage provider. Ideally, I would stay with Microsoft Azure, but I am open to S3 or other options if they are available.

Comment: SSIS export job?

Answer (score 1):

A [SSIS package](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10337.migrating-data-to-sql-azure-using-ssis.aspx) to move the data would be the route I'd go. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045619/sql-azure-backups) has many suggestions of solutions users tried apart from SSIS, incl 3rd party tools.